# Refer to column "name" instead of number in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, tableheader

I have a Google sheet with the following layout:

[image]

In my Google Script, I want to reference the columns by their titles (e.g., "Email", "Subject", "Message").

So instead of

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
var rowRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 18).getValues();
rowRange[0][1]
```

I want to do something like:

```
....
rowRange[0]["Email"]
```

Note: I do *not* want to determine and/or reference the number of the column *first* and *then* assign the name.

I want to manually enter the name in my code.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.  You will refer to them as row.Email, row.Subject, row.Message.

```
function callemByTheirTitle() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    var row=[];
    for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++)
    {
      row[hA[j]]=vA[i][j];
    }
    Logger.log('Email:%s Subject: %s Message: %s',row.Email,row.Subject,row.Message);
  }

}
```